# how to safely replace all whitespaces with underscores with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This works for any strings that have whitespaces in them

```
str.downcase.tr!(" ", "_")
```

but strings that dont have whitespaces just get deleted

So "New School" would change into "new_school" but "color" would be "", nothing!

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but I think it's `str.gsub! /\s/, '_'`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The docs for [tr!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-tr-21) say

> Translates str in place, using the same rules as String#tr. Returns str, or nil if no changes were made.

I think you'll get the correct results if you use [tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-tr) without the exclamation.

Comment: Indeed, `!` changes whatever is calling it, whereas without the `!` it returns a new string

Answer (score 158):

Pass '_' as parameter to [parameterize(separator: '-')](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-parameterize). For Rails 4 and below, use `str.parameterize('_')`

##### Examples:

> with space

```
str = "New School"
str.parameterize(separator: '_')

=> "new_school"
```

> without space

```
str = "school"
str.parameterize(separator: '_')

=> "school"
```

You can also solve this by chaining [underscore](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-underscore) to parameterize.

##### Examples:

> with space

```
str = "New School"
str.parameterize.underscore

=> "new_school"
```

> without space

```
str = "school"
str.parameterize.underscore

=> "school"
```

Comment: Be careful. `parameterize` will convert more than spaces--many special characters will be converted too. The intent of `parameterize` is to make a string URL-friendly.

Comment: Be careful as there is no `String#parameterize` in Ruby. There is `String#parameterize` in Rails, though.

Comment: And parameterize no longer takes an argument.

Comment: On Rails 5, use `str.parameterize(separator: '_')`.

Answer (score 39):

If you're interested in getting a string in [snake case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), then the proposed solution doesn't quite work, because you may get concatenated underscores and starting/trailing underscores.

For example

```
1.9.3-p0 :010 > str= "  John   Smith Beer "
  => "  John   Smith Beer " 
1.9.3-p0 :011 > str.downcase.tr(" ", "_")
  => "__john___smith_beer_"
```

This solution below would work better:

```
1.9.3-p0 :010 > str= "  John   Smith Beer "
  => "  John   Smith Beer " 
1.9.3-p0 :012 > str.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_")
  => "john_smith_beer"
```

squish is a String method provided by Rails

Comment: I figure ```str.downcase.split.join('_')``` could also work if #squish is not available ;)

Answer (score 17):

If you are using rails 5 and above you can achieve the same thing with

```
str.parameterize(separator: '_')
```

Note, this is not the exact same as `.parameterize.underscore`:

```rb
"New School 1-2".parameterize( separator: "_" ) #=> "new_school_1-2"
"New School 1-2".parameterize.underscore        #=> "new_school_1_2"
```

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but...

For **all** whitespace you probably want something more like this:

```
"hey\t there   world".gsub(/\s+/, '_') # hey_there_world
```

This gets tabs and new lines as well as spaces and replaces with a single `_`.

The regex can be modified to suit your needs.  E.g:

```
"hey\t there   world".gsub(/\s/, '_') # hey__there___world
```

Answer (score 8):

```
str.downcase.tr(" ", "_")
```

Note: No "!"

Answer (score 2):

You can also do
str.gsub(" ", "_")

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "Foo Bar"
str.tr(' ','').underscore

=> "foo_bar"
```